# Adding Multiple Alerts to a Single Alert View in Xcode

Tags: xcode, alert, alertview

First off I am fairly new to xcode. I am trying to add multiple alerts to a single view. I am creating a form for an ipad which allows the users to enter in information into text boxes. Since there are multiple text boxes that are required to fill out, I don't want multiple alert boxes to pop up displaying every error, but instead I want one alert view to show multiple errors. the commented code down below is how I imagine it might be written

```
- (IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name" //"Address" 
                                   //if name=nil  message:@"PLease fill out your name"
                               //if address=nilmessage:@"PLease fill out your address"



delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

[message show];
```

}

*Is it possible to put if statements before and after the messages to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
- (IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender {
        NSString *theMessage = @"";
        if (textField.text.length == 0) {
        theMessage = @"hey";
        } else if (textField2.text.length == 0) {
        theMessage = @"hey2";
        } else if (textField.text.length == 0) && (textField2.text.length == 0) {
        theMessage = @"doubleHey";
        }

        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name"
                                                message:theMessage
                                                delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];  
        [message show];
        [message release];
}
```

Comment: You can append string message according to your requirement of message to be displayed to user.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, if you make a edit to my answer I will happily accept it though!

Answer (score 1):

You can append message multiply by doing this:

```
 - (IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender {
    NSString *theMessage = @"PLease fill out your ";
    BOOL nameFlag = FALSE;
    if(name.length == 0)
    {  nameFlag = TRUE // For appending message
      [theMessage stringByAppendingFormat:@"name"];
    }

    if(address.length == 0)
    {
       if(nameFlag){ 
      [theMessage stringByAppendingFormat:@"& address"
       }
       else
       {    
         [theMessage stringByAppendingFormat:@"address"
        }
    }


    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message"
                                            message:theMessage
                                            delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];  
    [message show];
    [message release];
 }
```